# Send beep signal to Datalogic Barcodescanner in C#

Tags: c#, barcode

This is my last hope, Datalogic support did not respond...
I just want to send a 'Beep' signal to a Datalogic PM9300 wireless scanner in C#. It is connected with RS232 to the PC. The manual says I have to send it like this:
[Scanner address] [Delimiter] DC2 MESSAGE

I just want to send an LED signal or beep, like this:
  `ESC [ 6 q ESC [3 q ESC [7 q`
   (LED on, beep, LED off).

I tried a lot of snippets like:

```
_serialPort.Write(new byte[] { 27 }, 0, 1);
_serialPort.Write(new byte[] { 91 }, 0, 1);
_serialPort.Write(new byte[] { 51}, 0, 1);
_serialPort.Write(new byte[] { 113}, 0, 1);
_serialPort.Write(new byte[]  {13}, 0, 1);
```

Etc. Etc.
The scanner did not do anything... Input from RSs232 is OK of course.

Have anyone experience with C# + Datalogic scanners? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: do you - by any chance - have to documentation to this? i need to interact with datalogic scanners but my customer cant seem to find the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your code doesn't look like it is sending the right codes. Have you tried:

```
// Send: ESC [ 6 q CR
_serialPort.Write(new byte[] { 0x1B, 0x5B, 0x36, 0x71, 0x0D }, 0, 5);

// Send: ESC [ 3 q CR
_serialPort.Write(new byte[] { 0x1B, 0x5B, 0x33, 0x71, 0x0D }, 0, 5);

// Send: ESC [ 7 q CR
_serialPort.Write(new byte[] { 0x1B, 0x5B, 0x37, 0x71, 0x0D }, 0, 5);
```

Comment: Thank you for the info, now it works! i did two mistakes: i have to address the scanner, DC2, message, CR 
+ i have to write hex numbers, so thx!